# Most Commonly used Ajax Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am learning AJAX, and so I wanted to know what are the most commonly used asp.net ajax controls.
EDIT:
Other than Update Panel, Scriptmanager, Timer.

Comment: " r d " ?? - Please use whole words.

Comment: Button, TextBox, Grid, Editor, Upload and many other.

All of them are part of the Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX suite: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/.

Answer (score 1):

If you're learning AJAX for asp.net web forms, I thoroughly recommend investing in the Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX as it will boost your productivity massively.

This is their demo site with the most commonly used AJAX controls on the front page. You can see more controls by clicking the "All Controls" button on the left of the screen.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The [UpdatePanel](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx)

Comment: Sorry my question was not very clear. I have edited the same.

Answer (score 0):

calendar extender, Modal Popup, Filtered Text Box , WaterMark, Auto Complete , Rating